# C# replace string according to a dictionary

Tags: c#, string

I want to escape customized symbols in customized way, e.g.

```
',' -> '__Comma__'
'?' -> '__QuestionMark__'
'/' -> '__Slash__'
...
```

What is the fastest way to do this?

[Related python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100017/fast-way-to-replace-a-string-according-to-dict)

Comment: please refer http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/629296/Remove-string-from-match-word-csharp

Comment: What do you mean by 'fast'? Is it about nanoseconds in some hypothetical optimization or is it about parallel processing of a few GB big text where a little initialization and thread management overhead is quite acceptable?

Comment: The fastest way is to not use strings, use the `unsafe` keyword and write a bunch of code that is a bear to maintain and makes everybody's eyes bleed.   To which the usual response is, "well, it doesn't have to be *that* fast".

Comment: @grek40 what is your solutions for "hypothetical optimization" and "few GB big text"? Are they different?

Comment: I wouldn't even bother to research an "hypothetical optimization" at all and I'll only start to think about the other if it is really what you actually need. At some point you leave the area of easy questions where an answer is readily available. Make sure to be precise about what you need before expecting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuilder` class was designed for the modification of same string object.

```
var builder = new StringBuilder(yourText);
builder.Replace(",", "__Comma__");
```

[StringBuilder.Replace Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h5afh4w(v=vs.110).aspx)